# Spring boot h2 auto configuration not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Even though there are already many questions on this topic, non of the answers have helped me so far.
The code of my application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

One example of my entities:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;

@Entity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private int customerId;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    private Date differenceSince;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;
    @OneToOne
    private User lastUpdatedBy;

//getters and setters ...
}
```

The dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I cannot find the issue, but the H2 Console doesn't contain any tables:
[image]
[image]

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

try to set your application.properties as below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username= (username)
spring.datasource.password=(password)
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't get any tables in the h2 console...